# Making a post request using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a post request to a rest API with the data from a form in my HTML code. I want the form to be posted when I click the submit button, however when i click submit nothing happens. Can anyone help me with why this isn't working?

I want to avoid using jQuery if possible.

Any help will be appreciated, cheers

My form:

```
    <form id="input_form">Please enter details:
        <label for="name">Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="Name"></label>
        <label for="age">Age: <input type="text" name="age" value="Age"></label>

        <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Add User">
    </form>
```

My Javascript:

```
    const processResponse = function() {
        let response = JSON.parse(this.response);
        console.log(response);
    };

    const encodeParameters = function(params) {
        var strArray = [];
        Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key) {
            var paramString = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" +                    encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
            strArray.push(paramString);
        });
        return strArray.join("&");
    };

    const makeAPIQuery = function(name, barcode) {
        let rootURL = "somewhere";

        let params = {
            name: name,
            age: age
        };

        let queryURL = rootURL + "?" + encodeParameters(params);
        console.log(queryURL);

        let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.addEventListener("load", processResponse);
        xhttp.open("POST", queryURL, true);
        xhttp.send();
    };

    let submitButton = document.getElementById("submit_button");
    submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        console.log(name);
        let barcode = document.getElementById("age").value;
        console.log(age);

        if (name && age) {
            makeAPIQuery(name, age);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting. Right now it's not clear at all what your question is.

Comment: Because your script adds an event listener to an element, I suggest that you make it inside window.onload = function () { /* your script here*/ }

replace "barcode" in the function makeAPIQuery by "age", same thing in the 6th line from the last (let barcode )

There is no elements with id(s) you called using document.getElementById()... I suggest that you, instead, use document.getElementsByName("name")[0].value and document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value . It's recommended to use setRequestHeader() when the method is "POST". Also, look how to prevent the default behaviour of "submit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First there is no element with `id`, you are trying to retrieve element with name property using `document.getElementById` , so change name property to id, and secondly when using `ajax` to submit form you need to prevent the default behavior using `e.preventDefault`

```js
const processResponse = function() {
  let response = JSON.parse(this.response);
  console.log(response);
};

const encodeParameters = function(params) {
  var strArray = [];
  Object.keys(params).forEach(function(key) {
    var paramString = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(params[key]);
    strArray.push(paramString);
  });
  return strArray.join("&");
};

const makeAPIQuery = function(name, age) {
  let rootURL = "somewhere";

  let params = {
    name: name,
    age: age
  };

  let queryURL = rootURL + "?" + encodeParameters(params);
  console.log(queryURL);

  let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.addEventListener("load", processResponse);
  xhttp.open("POST", queryURL, true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send();
};

let submitButton = document.getElementById("submit_button");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  console.log(name);
  let age = document.getElementById("age").value;
  if (name && age) {
    makeAPIQuery(name, age);
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="input_form">Please enter details:
  <label for="name">Name: <input type="text" id="name" value="Name"></label>
  <label for="age">Age: <input type="text" id="age" value="Age"></label>

  <input type="submit" id="submit_button" value="Add User">
</form>
```